# wxPython Custom Paint Event on StaticText erases StaticText Label

Tags: python, wxpython

I'm trying to use the paint event to draw a border around a static text. It works fine i think, only problem is that when I draw the border, the label for the static text gets erased. Is there some way that I can prevent this from happening? I guess i could store the label maybe before doing the paint and then just paint it back on??? But I need to be able to access the label of the static text programatically after the paint event. If i try to use SetLabel after doing the paint event, as in the following code, it erases the border I just painted.

Any help on how to preserve the label would be appreciated. Thanks.

```
import wx

class MyStaticText(wx.StaticText): 
        
    def __init__(self, parent): 
        
        super(MyStaticText, self).__init__(parent, id=wx.ID_ANY, label="Static Text", pos=wx.DefaultPosition, size=wx.Size(100, 100))  
        
        self.if_border = True
        self.Bind(wx.EVT_PAINT, self.OnPaint) 
        
    def OnPaint(self, e): 
        
        if not self.if_border:
            return
        
        dc = wx.PaintDC(self) 
        
        # get current size of static text
        curr_size = self.GetSize()
        curr_width = curr_size[0]
        curr_height = curr_size[1]

        # NOTE: pen_width needs to be an odd number
        pen_width = 3
        pen_cushion = ( pen_width - 1 ) / 2
                
        pen = wx.Pen(wx.Colour(0,0,255)) 
        pen.SetWidth(pen_width)
        dc.SetPen(pen) 
        
        print("curr_width=" + str(curr_width))
        print("curr_height=" + str(curr_height))
        print("pen_width=" + str(pen_width))
        print("pen_cushion=" + str(pen_cushion))
        
        # ok so we need to draw a rectangle
        # in other words 4 lines
        # x1, y1, x2, y2
        
        # a. left side
        start_x = 0 + pen_cushion
        end_x = 0 + pen_cushion
        start_y = 0
        end_y = curr_height
        dc.DrawLine(start_x, start_y, end_x, end_y) 
        
        # b. right side
        start_x = curr_width - pen_cushion
        end_x = curr_width - pen_cushion
        start_y = 0
        end_y = curr_height
        dc.DrawLine(start_x, start_y, end_x, end_y) 
        
        # c. top side
        start_x = 0
        end_x = curr_width
        start_y = 0 + pen_cushion
        end_y = 0 + pen_cushion
        dc.DrawLine(start_x, start_y, end_x, end_y) 
        
        # c. bottom side
        start_x = 0
        end_x = curr_width
        start_y = curr_height - pen_cushion
        end_y = curr_height - pen_cushion
        dc.DrawLine(start_x, start_y, end_x, end_y) 
        

        # the label get's overwritten on paint event, have to re-insert it?
        # this completely undoes the paint event
        self.SetLabel("EHHH!")
```

Comment: Dont use self.SetLabel() in OnPaint method. The device context provides a method for drawing text.
https://wxpython.org/Phoenix/docs/html/wx.DC.html#wx.DC.DrawText

Answer (score 0):

Dont use self.SetLabel() in OnPaint method. The device context provides a method for drawing text.

> See [wx.DC.DrawText](https://wxpython.org/Phoenix/docs/html/wx.DC.html#wx.DC.DrawText)

Change this at the end of the OnPaint() method:

Replace that:

```
self.SetLabel("EHHH!")
```

With that:

```
text = 'Hello World!'
text_w, text_h = dc.GetTextExtent(text)
dc.DrawText("Hello World", curr_height / 2 - text_w / 2, curr_width / 2 - text_h / 2)
```